# How do I know that a form input has changed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I have a form generated by `<% Ajax.BeginForm() {} %>` which contains a lot of inputs and texareas.

When an input value change, I need to know about it and mark the input and the form as "dirty". If the user tries to leave the page without saving, I will ask him or her to confirm abandoning changes.

Any suggestion to how this should be done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The html controls include a property that holds the original value.  You could compare this value with the current value to see if there have been any changes.

```
function getHasChanges() {
    var hasChanges = false;

    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if ((this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden") && this.defaultValue != this.value) {
            hasChanges = true;
            return false;             }
        else {
            if ((this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox") && this.defaultChecked != this.checked) {
                hasChanges = true;
                return false;                 }
            else {
                if ((this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple")) {
                    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                        if (this.options[x].selected != this.options[x].defaultSelected) {
                            hasChanges = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return hasChanges;
}

function acceptChanges() {
    $(":input:not(:button):not([type=hidden])").each(function () {
        if (this.type == "text" || this.type == "textarea" || this.type == "hidden") {
            this.defaultValue = this.value;
        }
        if (this.type == "radio" || this.type == "checkbox") {
            this.defaultChecked = this.checked;
        }
        if (this.type == "select-one" || this.type == "select-multiple") {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
                this.options[x].defaultSelected = this.options[x].selected
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I really like this way of checking if the value is equal to the default value, and I guess this would work just fine in a "traditional form". I will, however, submit the changes through an XMLHttpRequest and I need to "reset" the form when the submit is successful. Is there a nice way I can _set_ the defaultValue/defaultChecked etc. to the current value?

Comment: Thanks. I made some more changes by adding the number field. :)

Comment: Thumbs up for speeding this up and using "this" instead of "$(this)" to get the pure javascript "type".

Answer (score 35):

Resurrecting this old question because I thought of a simpler/better way. Instead of listening to events on the various inputs, you can serialize the initial form data, store it, and then serialize it again later and check if it's changed, like this:

```
var originalFormData = $('form#formId').serialize();
function checkFormChanged() {
    if(originalFormData !== $('form#formId').serialize()) {
        //it's dirty!
    }
}
```

One additional advantage here is that if the user makes a change and then *reverts* it, this check will report the form as clean.

Comment: This is the best answer undoubtedly

Comment: A good solution, but didn't work for me for forms with input type=file

Comment: This is genius, exactly what I needed! No need for looping over inputs or anything like that

Answer (score 26):

From jQuery Docs:

```
//This applies to whole form
$('#formID').change(function() {
  alert('Form changed!');
});
```

And you could do like this to check only the inputs and have user notified, if they try to exit without saving changes.

```
var inputsChanged = false;
$('#formID input').change(function() {
  inputsChanged = true;
});

$(window).unload(function() {
  if (inputsChanged === true) {
    alert('Would you like to save your edits before exiting?'); 
  }    
});
```

[jQuery API .change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: This worked great for me. Plus it's way more simple and uses less code than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

I would do this with jQuery. It would be something like this (just a draft, you may need to add/change some code):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#formId:input').each(function(key) {
        $(this).change(function() {
            $(this).addClass('dirty');
        });
    });
});
```

Then, before POSTing, check if there is a dirty input. You can even add some color by using the dirty css class.

EDIT: typo fixed 'changed' to 'change'

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery plugin dirrty for identifying form dirty.

https://github.com/rubentd/dirrty

In on("dirty") event set some global variable to true to identify form has changed.

Handle `window.onbeforeunload` or `$(window).unload()` event and get confirmation from user based on that variable value.

The advantage of this plugin is you can track back if form is changed to original values again using 'on("clean") event